# Importar libreria a Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de importar una libreria a mi proyecto de android, el problema es que esa libreria que he descargado es un proyecto java con fichero. java en vez de .jar.

Influye en algo o directamente solo se pueden importar los . jar

Comment: No tiene para ponerse como dependencia en el graddle?

Comment: Porque no aportar más datos como el nombre de la "library" al menos...

Comment: Era una pregunta general la librería en concreto es una para consumir datos burdatiles. Pero me han aclarado la duda por otro lado asi que cerrare lampregunta por mal planteamiento.

Comment: @EduardoMéndez Yo opino que no existe pregunta mala, en alguna parte y algun momento alguien le pasara lo mismo y googleara su problema y saldra esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es importar una libreria, las librerias normalmente tienen su forma de instalacion por medio de Maven,Graddle,Ivy, etc ...

Busca en la documentacion de tu libreria el codigo que pondrias en tu Graddle en las dependencias algo asi :

```
dependencies {
    compile  soyunadirecciondedependencia:22.17.1 (Version de ejemplo, la version puede variar) etc etc etc
}
```